# Microsoft access change the date format from dd/m/yyyy = 28/9/2018 to dd/mm/yyyy = 28/09/2018 and its all data

Tags: date, crystal-reports, vb6, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

i want to change the date format of my microsoft access because of im having a problem displaying the data of my program on datagridview and crystal report.because the program is supposed to read the date on dd/mm/yyyy but on my microsoft access it is format on dd/m/yyyy. is possible to change it to dd/mm/yy and all records in my database thanksss.

Comment: visual basic 6.0 sir.

Answer (score 0):

Date values carry no format. However, a *default format* - as to your system settings - is applied whenever a date value is displayed to make it human readable.

So, either change your system settings, or apply the format you prefer to the *Format* property of any control (textbox) where a date value is displayed: dd/mm/yyyy

How the dates are displayed in Crystal Reports is not related to VB.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that whether Crystal Reports supports custom formatting and how is not a VB6 question.

As for a DataGrid, it is fairly simple:

```
'Reference to: Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library 6.0 (SP6)
Set StdDataFormat = New StdFormat.StdDataFormat
With StdDataFormat
    .Type = fmtCustom
    .Format = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = RS
Set DataGrid1.Columns(0).DataFormat = StdDataFormat
```